# Fullcalendar not rendering events

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar Angular version with a .net core backend.

I am using the event stream and it is bringing back the events nicely whenever I change dates etc.

But the events are not rendering on the calender.

This is the output from my api:

```
[{"id":"83220","title":"Tiffany in Office","start":"2022/12/12 09:30 AM","end":"2022/12/12 10:00 AM"},
{"id":"83338","title":"Jamed","start":"2022/12/12 02:00 PM","end":"2022/12/12 03:00 PM"},
{"id":"83465","title":"IAG in Office","start":"2022/12/12 11:30 AM","end":"2022/12/12 12:30 PM"}]
```

And these are my calendar options:

```
smallCalendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
  initialView: 'timeGridDay',
  height: '100%',
  allDaySlot: true,
  displayEventTime: true,
  nowIndicator: true,
  events: this.loadSmallEvents.bind(this)
};
```

I'm on Angular 13 using FullCalendar 5.11.3 with daygrid, interaction and timegrid installed.

Comment: Make it show the event data with `-` instead of `/` as the date separator

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing for details